# NetLogo: histogram with list of strings

Tags: histogram, netlogo

I just tried to create a histogram build upon a list of characters like this:

```
histogram [a c a c b c a c c c c c c a c c a c a c a a c c c a a b c b c]
```

But it doesn't show anything.
Is it just supposed to handle numbers or am I missing something?

Comment: Use code formatting, don't use your sign in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn´t use quotes in your histogram list, but I am assuming that you wanted to plot a list of strings like ["a" "b" "c" ...], right?

As far as I know, it is not possible to use categorical values (like strings) for a histogram in netlogo plots. This is also stated in the netlogo dictionary:
histogram [...] Any non-numeric values in the list are ignored. [...]

One way to solve this would be a conversion to a numeric list by just giving every string-character a specific number:

```
  let m ["a" "c" "a" "c" "b" "c" "a" "a" "c" "c" "b" "b" "c" "c" "a" "a"]
  let n [ ]

  foreach m
  [
    if (? = "a") [set n lput 0 n]
    if (? = "b") [set n lput 1 n]
    if (? = "c") [set n lput 2 n]
   ;...
  ]

  histogram n
```

Comment: shorter: `histogram map [position ? ["a" "b" "c"]] m`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, and sorry for not writing the quotes, as I did in the original code. I will try it as Seth suggested: that looks like a smart way to get around that limitation.

Answer (score -1):

histogram work as you said. It's not easy to help you with as little information about your code. For me the error can come from 2 ways :

1. the plot context definition need to be in bar (i.e image)
2. the `x-range` plot definition need to be defined

for the 2nd hypothese some thing like

```
set-plot-x-range 0 ( (max myliste) + 5)
histogram myliste
let maxbar modes myliste
let maxrange length filter [ ? = item 0 maxbar ] myliste
set-plot-y-range 0 1000
```

In the plot on code interface may work

[image: plot definition in netlogo]

If you choose the 2nd ways, you don't need tout defined the scale like on the screenshot